# Confused on using button OnClick to call Ajax from button with table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC app that I'm writing our records to a table. On each record it has a "Delete" button that I want to call Ajax from. However I've had some confusing results.

Initially I set this up to use a CSS class on the button to kick off some Ajax. This table is inserted via a _PartialView which might be part of he problem. This code works fine until I actually call the Ajax function which reloads the table after removing the deleted record. After the partial view reload, the onClick will no longer work.

This is my HTML and I'm using the removeEmp class on the button for use with Ajax.

```
<td>
    <button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger removeEmp">
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete
    </button>
    @Html.Hidden("RID",item.RID, new { @class = "rid"})
</td>
```

This is the original Ajax call I created and it works until you actually call the Ajax which will reload the table after deleting the record. I'm using Bootbox to display my confirmation box.

```
$('.removeEmp').click(function (e) {

    alert('clicked');

    var rid = $(this).siblings(".rid:hidden").val();
    var empId = $(this).closest("tr").children('td.empid').text();
    var url = "/Employee/EmployeeRemoveAccess/?" + $.param({ "employeeId": empId, "rid": rid });            

    bootbox.confirm({
        message: "Are you sure you want to delete this employee?<br /><strong>" + fullName + " (" + empId + ")</strong>",
        buttons: {
            cancel: {
                label: '<i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> Cancel'
            },
            confirm: {
                label: '<i class="far fa-check"></i> Confirm',
                className: 'btn-success'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result === true) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#divLoading").hide();
                        $("#accessListWrapper").html(response);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        $("#divLoading").hide();

                        if (xhr.status == 500) {
                            alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status + '\nError: Internal Server Error;');
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

});
```

When researching the issue I read some posts that say you have to use the .on('click') for tables that are dynamically created. So, I changed the selector to the following and I get the same results. It will display the "alert" and bootbox confirm, then delete the record, reload the partial view, but then the "Delete" button doesn't do or display anything after the reload. No errors in the console either.

```
$('.removeEmp').on('click',(function (e) {

    alert('clicked');
....
}));
```

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, no need for the extra parentheses in front of the Function

```
$(document).on('click','.removeEmp',function (e) {

    alert('clicked');
....
});
```

Comment: Got it, using the DOM, attach the click event to any object with the '.removeEmp' class. I'm still a little confused why I couldn't attach it to the objects with css class after reload unless once it's been reloaded it can't see the css class?

Comment: Correct DOM is loaded initially and thats it. If you have dynamic data (data loaded after DOM) then you need the `on` event to find the new loaded data in DOM. The `click` event will only look at last loaded DOM

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).find('.removeEmp').on('click', function (e) {
    //...
});
```